# Cannot open many Images in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

This is my code:

```
foreach (Database.Photo photo in eventPhotos)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Height = 100;
            img.Width = 80;
            img.Focusable = true;
            img.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(img_MouseDown);
            string littleString = photo.PhotoUrl;
            littleString = littleString.Replace(".jpg", "t.jpg");
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(littleString, UriKind.Absolute);
            bi.EndInit();
            img.Source = bi;
            imagesEvent1.Children.Add(img);
        }
```

But not all images are loaded.:

[image]

in this time, images №3,5 are not loaded, in next time other images are not loaded.

Comment: Are you getting the images from the internet? The download may be failing.

Comment: yes, from internet. Internet: 2Mb/s

Comment: Well just because your internet is fast and the images are small doesn't mean the download should succeed. Try handling the ImageFailed event on the Image control and see if that fires.

Comment: Thanks! How I can mark your answer as marked?)

Comment: @GLeBaTi - @RandomEngy has now posted their suggestion as an answer. You can now accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image download may be failing. Try handling the ImageFailed event on the Image control and see if that fires.